# What is the best way to add NumberPicker for android?

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I have to support numberpicker version from 2.2 android. What is the best way to do this? In versions more than 3.0 it works fine. But in early releases of android it hasn't supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a custom NumberPicker such as [this example project](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) which was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205060/how-would-one-implement-a-numberpicker-in-android-api-7).

Comment: Or use this backport: https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker